# Updating a specific div id class

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm not succeeding in changing the class of the id. The other functions in the code are working. I want to add an extra css class when the `div` is clicked.

```html
<div id='31589' onclick='AddSeat(this.id)'>html</div>
<div id='31590' onclick='AddSeat(this.id)'>html</div>
<div id='31591' onclick='AddSeat(this.id)'>html</div>
```

```js
function AddSeat(str) {
  if (str == "") {
    document.getElementById("Winkelmand").innerHTML = "";
    return;
  } else { 
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
      // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
      xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
      // code for IE6, IE5
      xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
        document.getElementById("Winkelmand").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
      }
    };
    xmlhttp.open("GET","winkelmand.php?q=" + str, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
    $(document.getElementById(str).className) += 'myseat';
  }
}
```

Comment: `document.getElementById(str).className +=' myseat';`

Comment: since you have jQuery `$('#' + str).addClass('myseat')`

Comment: `document.getElementById(str).classList.add('myseat')`

Comment: Or `document.getElementById(str).classList.add(CLASS_NAME)`

Comment: Thanks.  I tried a lot and now it seems so easy :-)

Comment: If you're using jQuery, why code Ajax manually?

Answer (score 0):

document.getElementById is not a jQuery function, but you are using $-sign which is for jQuery.

So either remove the $-sign sign or use the second suggestion by Arun P Johny:

```
$('#' + str).addClass('myseat')
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this JSFiddle will help: https://jsfiddle.net/ojgqkg8q/

Since you have JQuery already, I took the liberty of converting your previous AJAX code to JQuery AJAX, which is much cleaner and shorter. It also uses the addClass() method suggested by Arun P Johny to add the class to the DOM element. Obviously, in this JSFiddle the AJAX request will not actually work, as winkelmand.php is not available, but if you copy the code to your own site, it should work.

Short answer is:

```
$('#'+str).addClass('myseat');
```

as suggested by Arun P Johny.